# React: how using with axios 'withCredentials'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have server (Node.js + Express + CORS) with API(as 'login' via JWT) and React client app with login via server's API. It is needed to send coockies via axios

```
withCredentials = true ,
```

but if server + react running on the 192.168.0.1 and client (Web browser) see from 192.168.0.!1 - it is next error:

```
'Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at `http://localhost:5002/api/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:3000’).`
```

Note: axios without `withCredentials = true` working good with server's cors with `origin: '*'`, but no 'auto coockies' from client in this case.

My question: what is right way create React axios with auto coockies
(via

```
withCredentials = true
```

) for any client in the Internet ?

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39KKT.png)

Comment: Please edit your your Question to improve the formatting. This will help others to find a solution for you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

express app:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

react app:

```
function App() {
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:5000/api";
```

package.json in react app:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a answer similar to your problem: [enter link description here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1661)

The code is working correctly although the 'origin' must be '*' value (string) not a boolean.

```
const corsConfig = {
  origin: true,
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsConfig));
app.options('*', cors(corsConfig));
```

The 'origin' opt should be something like this (by docs):

```
const corsConfig = {
      origin: '*',
      credentials: true,
    };
```

Either Express or CORS is broken - I don`t know which.

Comment: I found answer TO MY PROBLEM, not 'similar to your...'

Comment: I dont know why but I tried your answer, it did not work,

but follow your link and apply solution from there, and it worked in my side